# Is it possible to integrate RPi to a PC's GPIO?

Tags: gpio, arduino, rpi.gpio

What I mean to say I want to try something in the lines of sending a SMS to the RPi to activate my PC.

i.e. turn on the PC or turn off.

I understand there are of different architectures but is there a way? For example an Arduino?

Comment: Yes it is possible and there allot of discussion on this Q&A about controlling relays, using Arduinos and integrating with Raspberry Pi GPIO. Please use the search. Please consider asking a more specific question- We can discuss 100 different ways to do it. That is not the purpose of a [Q&A](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Just curious, how do you plan to receive the SMS message on the Raspberry Pi?  Are planning to use a USB cell modem or some public or private SMS gateway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) is an easier option and does not involve hardware manipulations. AFAIK, WOL is supported by most of common PC hardware.

Comment: +1 for WOL- But I know for a fact that not all computers on the shelf support WOL- especially budget Motherbaords or PC's built using budget components. I know any Dell/HP supports them becasue they are business oriented. But the likes of Acer/Asus have mixed. And most budget products do not use WOL. So you have to check if it does support it. Usually the BIOS has a WOL feature if it is embedded.

Comment: Can WOL also be used to turn it off again?? I did not see any references to such option.

Comment: ikku - you cant use WOL to turn it off :) unless there is a SOL (Sleep On Lan) that I do not know about. hehehe :)

Comment: when your computer is running, there are many ways of telling it to shut down - RPC, Services, etc...

Comment: To turn it off, a 'sudo halt' through ssh should do.

Answer (score 1):

- [Here are some links to Arduino searches on this site.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=arduino)
- [These are results for using Relays](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=relay)
- [Some good Q&A's about GPIO's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=GPIO)
- [A few topics on WOL of the Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=WOL)